# How to Show or Hide the page redirect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

screenshot2

[image]

screenshot1

[image]

I have 4 fields in a form

1. Product Field.
2. Brand Field.
3. Services Field.

I want to show them all in the index, but when i go to the product url i want to show only product field and services field

I have tried .show and hide method but it's hiding the field for all url

I am trying this method to hide and Now it's hiding as per my request but compromising in the form field, and I don't want that there's an empty blank space.

### The issue was different and it fixed now what I did was I created  a different id and call the particular id, without compromising the margin and all and it's working like charm now.

```
<div style="display:none;" class="appointment" id="booking-form-modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">

  <form method="POST" action="/submit-request" onsubmit="submitRequest();">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <select id="productDropdown" class="form-control" name="product" required>
        <option value="">Select Products</option>
        @foreach($products as $product)
        <option value="{{ $product['id']}}">{{ $product['name']}}</option>
        @endforeach

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div  class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
          <select id="brandDropdown" class="form-control" name="brands" required>
            <option value="">Select Brands</option>
          </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <select id="serviceDropdown" class="form-control" name="services" required>
          <option value="">Select Services</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Script to redirect as per the request

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if(/services|1800/.test(window.location.href))
    {
      document.getElementById('brandDropdown').style.display = 'none';
    }
});



</script>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried this one also but it did helps for few things but, this is not the right way to do.   `if (/repair/.test(window.location.href)) {


   document.getElementById('brandDropdown').style.display = 'none';
 }`

Comment: Can you post your current javascript code for hiding/showing the fields ?

Comment: If the issue is solved (and the answer is not what Recep Karadas answrered), please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How does your url look like and when do you call the provided snippet?
Could you also provide a more detailed example of your code?

I guess you want to hide the elements "onload"?
If so, then you need to wait until your elements are loaded.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if(/repair/.test(window.location.href)) 
    { 
      document.getElementById('brandDropdown').closest('.row').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
});
```

Comment: okay same method i tried before..but it compromised the margin of field which i dont want.

Comment: what do you mean by compromised the margin? Could you show us?

Comment: screenshot uploaded

Comment: Ok, could you now provide the html part where you add the four elements.

Comment: kindly refer above. Thank you

Comment: Updated my answer. Added .closest('.row')

Comment: I used another ID for the brands field and its working like a charm. Thank you all

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, I added another id so that it didn't compromise my form fields, kindly find the solution below.

```
<div id="branddrop-row" class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <select id="brandDropdown" class="form-control" name="brands" required>
        <option value="">Select Brands</option>
      </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the script for hiding as per the request. I call the div id instead of select id so that it didn't compromise my form fields.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if(/services|1800/.test(window.location.href))
    {
      document.getElementById('branddrop-row').style.display = 'none';
    }
});



</script>
```